# How do I trade my friend's genuines?

Tags: team-fortress-2

My friend got some genuines, and he wants to give them to me, being that he does not play TF2. I got on his account and got them, but they are untradable, even though some of them are from older games. Is there a certain time that must be waited from the time they are earned. He is not premium, but he can become one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Genuine items are always tradable. However, if you're not premium on TF2 and you look only through the Steam inventory interface, every item (except those you've received from trades with premium members) will have the `Not Tradable` tag.

Once your friend upgrades to premium, the `Not Tradable` tag will be removed from all items aside from achievement items.

Comment: You must be aware that not all Genuine items are always tradable, and some may take some time before promo restrictions are lifted on them. If your friend plans on trying to trade them before the restrictions are lifted, they must use Gift Wrap to "trade" it out.

Answer (score 2):

In order to trade genuines from a non-premium account, that account must become premium to trade. The easiest way to do this is to buy a $.49 item from the Mann Co. Store. If you use the "try out" feature, you'll get a discount that should bring it down to about $.36.